# Issue accessing external exadata database from docker

Tags: oracle, docker, exadata

I am having a problem accessing external exadata database from docker.

Docker File:

```
FROM centos:7.3.1611
WORKDIR /tmp

ADD . /tmp
ENV http_proxy=<added>
ENV https_proxy=<added>

ENV RHEL_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ENV ORACLE_INSTANTCLIENT_MAJOR=12.2
ENV ORACLE_INSTANTCLIENT_VERSION=12.2.0.1.0
ENV ORACLE=/usr
ENV ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE/lib/oracle/$ORACLE_INSTANTCLIENT_MAJOR/client64
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/lib
ENV C_INCLUDE_PATH=$C_INCLUDE_PATH:$ORACLE/include/oracle/$ORACLE_INSTANTCLIENT_MAJOR/client64

RUN yum update && yum install -y libaio1 \
        curl rpm2cpio cpio \
    && mkdir $ORACLE && TMP_DIR="$(mktemp -d)" && cd "$TMP_DIR" \
    && oracle-instantclient$ORACLE_INSTANTCLIENT_MAJOR-basic-$ORACLE_INSTANTCLIENT_VERSION-1.x86_64.rpm -o basic.rpm \
    && rpm2cpio basic.rpm | cpio -i -d -v && cp -r usr/* $ORACLE && rm -rf ./* \
    && ln -s libclntsh.so.12.1 $ORACLE/lib/oracle/$ORACLE_INSTANTCLIENT_MAJOR/client64/lib/libclntsh.so.$ORACLE_INSTANTCLIENT_MAJOR \
    && ln -s libocci.so.12.1 $ORACLE/lib/oracle/$ORACLE_INSTANTCLIENT_MAJOR/client64/lib/libocci.so.$ORACLE_INSTANTCLIENT_MAJOR \
    && oracle-instantclient$ORACLE_INSTANTCLIENT_MAJOR-devel-$ORACLE_INSTANTCLIENT_VERSION-1.x86_64.rpm -o devel.rpm \
    && rpm2cpio devel.rpm | cpio -i -d -v && cp -r usr/* $ORACLE && rm -rf "$TMP_DIR" \
    && echo "$ORACLE_HOME/lib" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle.conf && chmod o+r /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle.conf && ldconfig \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove curl rpm2cpio cpio

RUN pip --no-cache-dir install Flask==0.12.2

ENV SHELL /bin/bash

EXPOSE 80

# WORKDIR /docker

ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

Error:returned a non-zero code: 1

Can anyone help me to resolve this?

Comment: What returned a non-zero code? You're probably going to have to give us a little more information here ;) Is it failing on the build? On the run? What commands are you using to build / run?

Comment: It is failing on build. Build command i am running is docker build --no-cache -t ck.base .

Answer (score 0):

The build command fails when executing the below command:

```
RUN yum update && yum install -y libaio1 \
        curl rpm2cpio cpio \
    && mkdir $ORACLE && TMP_DIR="$(mktemp -d)" && cd "$TMP_DIR" \
    && oracle-instantclient$ORACLE_INSTANTCLIENT_MAJOR-basic-$ORACLE_INSTANTCLIENT_VERSION-1.x86_64.rpm -o basic.rpm \
    && rpm2cpio basic.rpm | cpio -i -d -v && cp -r usr/* $ORACLE && rm -rf ./* \
    && ln -s libclntsh.so.12.1 $ORACLE/lib/oracle/$ORACLE_INSTANTCLIENT_MAJOR/client64/lib/libclntsh.so.$ORACLE_INSTANTCLIENT_MAJOR \
    && ln -s libocci.so.12.1 $ORACLE/lib/oracle/$ORACLE_INSTANTCLIENT_MAJOR/client64/lib/libocci.so.$ORACLE_INSTANTCLIENT_MAJOR \
    && oracle-instantclient$ORACLE_INSTANTCLIENT_MAJOR-devel-$ORACLE_INSTANTCLIENT_VERSION-1.x86_64.rpm -o devel.rpm \
    && rpm2cpio devel.rpm | cpio -i -d -v && cp -r usr/* $ORACLE && rm -rf "$TMP_DIR" \
    && echo "$ORACLE_HOME/lib" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle.conf && chmod o+r /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle.conf && ldconfig \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove curl rpm2cpio cpio
```

Comment: any help on the above issue ?